# sorting a List of integers pairs such that List[(Int,Int)] in scala

Tags: scala

i have a list i.e.

```html
List[(Int,Int)]=((5,12),(2,3),(3,14),(4,5),(1,0))
```

i want to sort the each 2nd item on the basis of first and place it in a List[Int] i.e.
List[Int]=(12,5,14,3,0)
what i should do in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sortBy` and `map`

```scala
scala> val xs = List((5,12),(2,3),(3,14),(4,5),(1,0))
xs: List[(Int, Int)] = List((5,12), (2,3), (3,14), (4,5), (1,0))

scala> xs.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2).reverse
res1: List[Int] = List(12, 5, 14, 3, 0)
```

Note that `sortBy` by default does ascending order so you need to `.reverse` the resulting List

Comment: It's faster to sort by the opposite of `_._1`, ie `.sortBy(-_._1)`.